# Converting State Plane (Nevada) to UTM

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm

I've received a database of drill hole locations in SPCS but I only use UTM.

How can I convert a CSV spreadsheet from State Plane Coordinate System, Nevada East NAD27 TO UTM?

Here's a video of the process I'm following with no success.

https://vimeo.com/669657507/e84405ce12

Comment: Please post some of your point file. QGIS can transform those points. Another option is to use the NCAT site: https://geodesy.noaa.gov/NCAT/

Comment: Thanks Kadir. Here's an excerpt (there are thousands that we have to convert):

Easting 400687.85 Northing 2414690.07; 
E 400412.31 N 2413816.15; 
E 396233 N 2413647; 
E 396191.6 N 2413557.5

Comment: PS I'm familiar with QGIS so if there's a way that would be great.

Comment: Create a new project in QGIS and set the CRS to the appropriate UTM zone. Then load the CSV file Layer->Add Layer-> Delimited Text Layer. It's critical that you set the Geometry CRS field in the dialog , otherwise it will assume something that is wrong. Once loaded, you can export the layer into whatever format with whatever CRS you want.

Comment: you probably could use [Corpscon](https://www.agc.army.mil/What-we-do/Corpscon/)

Comment: Thanks Llaves, I'm able to import with no probs and things look correct but each time I export and change the CRS the exported CSV is just the same as the old one. Any ideas why that may be happening?

Comment: If you export to a CSV format and want to see the coordinates of the points in the new table, must configure that option in the export dialog. All other fields (also the old coordinates ones) will be copied to the new table, but you can disable them in the export dialog, too, if you want.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel - where is that option? I don't see an option to enable the new coordinates, nor do I see an option to disable the old ones. Here's a screen capture showing exactly how I'm doing this... do you see something missing? https://vimeo.com/669657507/e84405ce12

Comment: Thanks all - figured it out: I needed to add a selection to the GEOMETRY in LAYER OPTIONS: as_xy and that adds the converted data columns to the spreadsheet. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Layer >> Add Layer >> Add Delimited Text Layer >> Export >> Save Features As

In the newly created layer, Open Attribute Table >> Click the Edit Pencil >> Field Calculator.

Add 2 new fields:

x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:32007', 'EPSG:32611'))

y(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:32007', 'EPSG:32611'))
[image]
Export >> Save Features As >> CSV Format:

E_32007,N_32007,E_32611,N_32611

400687.85,2414690.07,588119.058,4581576.026

400412.31,2413816.15,588039.455,4581308.374

396233.00,2413647.00,586766.880,4581236.018

396191.60,2413557.50,586754.711,4581208.542